# I want to show my post for limited time, how is it possible?

Tags: posts, archives, limit

I want to make one website like a newspaper, so i want to show my daily post for one day or limited time, after one day previous post will go to archive and no longer show on web page, how is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `cron job`.  Yes WordPress has a function `wp_schedule_event ()`.  This function will perform certain operations based on the time  difference you add it.

Say for example,  if you schedule it `daily` this will works everyday and perform the operarions on daily basis. 
you can hook a function with `wp_schedule_event`.  Just get the published posts list and from the posts check the date of publish and current time.  If it marches today leave it.  Otherwise you can edit the post and change the status as draft or you can even delete it. 
Here I didn't give you code samples.  If you require there are many question available  about cron job and post status change.  Just Go through it.